# Failed to found StaticLoggerBinder in project

Tags: java, log4j2

I have project with some modules. In parent I have defined:

org.apache.logging.log4j
    log4j-slf4j-impl
    ${version.log4j}
    runtime

but when I want to deploy application then StaticLoggerBinder is not found:

```
No org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder found in ClassPath, trying with log4j...
```

but when I add depenedcy just into this project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<version>${version.log4j}</version>
</dependency>
```

then 2 StaticLoggerBinder is founded:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hudect/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hudect/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.0-rc1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0-rc1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

as you can see second one is from my parent project. I am really confused why this happens. Can someone me explain me how should I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have the log4j-core and log4j-api dependencies?